# Enum inside the Array is not validting in json-schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am validating the json with json_schema.

Allowed values for ghrBillingCode should be only "I9NOT"

expected result should be error as 2nd and 3rd node is not I9NOT but it is validating json as correct.

What is wrong in json-schema i am using

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "invoiceLineInfo": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "ghrBillingCode": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "I9NOT"
                  ]
                },
                "quantity": {
                  "type": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "invoiceNumber": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

json:

```
[
   {
      "invoiceLineInfo":[
        {
           "ghrBillingCode":"I9NOT",
           "quantity":1
        },
        {
           "ghrBillingCode":"I9NOTRU",
           "quantity":2
        },
        {
           "ghrBillingCode":"I9PSUP",
           "quantity":1
        }
     ],
     "invoiceNumber":"202203010100301"
   }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your schema, you have extra brackets [] around the items array type. This means that the enum is checked for the first array element only and your example validates because the first item happens to be "I9NOT".

From your sample document, it seems like you expect the enum to apply to all array elements. To achieve this, simply drop the [] from the items value.

For the array / items syntax, have a look here:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#items

Comment: "The parser probably looks for an objects value under items and ignores the array." 

No, in draft4, the array form of items is interpreted as indicating the schema for each item in sequence - therefore there is only a schema defined for the first item, and all subsequent items will always validate.  This is clearly explained at the UJS page in the link.